# Get common first zero-value indice from three dense Eigen::MatrixXi in C++

Tags: c++, data-manipulation, eigen

I have a NxN nonnegative `Eigen::MatrixXi` called `cost_matrix`, and two Nx1 nonnegative `Eigen::VectorXi` called `rowVector` and `colVector`. I want to find the first indices (i, j) such that `cost_matrix(i, j)`, `rowVector(i)` and `colVector(j)` are all zeros.

I know there are some naive solutions like just traversing all elements, but they cost too much time. I want the most efficient way in Eigen C++.

Here is my current code, it's faster than traversing all elements by using `Eigen::DenseBase::visit`.

```
Eigen::MatrixXi cost_matrix(4,4);
cost_matrix<<1, 2, 3, 0, 
             5, 0, 0, 8,
             9, 8, 7, 6,
             0, 2, 1, 5;
Eigen::VectorXi rowCover(4);
Eigen::VectorXi colCover(4);
rowCover << 0, 0, 1, 1;
colCover << 1, 1, 0, 1;
//A data demo. Cost_matrix is a NxN nonnegative int matrix.
//RowCover and colCover are N nonnegative int vector.

int i, j;
cost_matrix.colwise() += rowCover;
cost_matrix.rowwise() += colCover.transpose();
Eigen::Index zeroRow, zeroCol;
int min = find_zero_matrix.transpose().minCoeff(&zeroCol, &zeroRow);
i = zeroRow;
j = zeroCol;
//the result should be
//i = 1
//j = 2
```

Comment: Your description doesn't match the code. Writing description of code is often just worse than writing the code. Please create a [mre].

Comment: As long as you activate optimization (and maybe deactivate assertions -- after you successfully tested your code), manual C++ will generally not be slower than Eigen code, unless Eigen would know a way to cleverly optimize your problem. It may or may not be more readable, though.

Comment: Can you change your input format, e.g. instead of storing `rowCover` as `[0 0 1 1]` can you directly store the indexes of the zero-entries (i.e., `{0, 1}`, either in a `std::vector` or `Eigen::VectorXi`)?

Comment: Some questions: 1. You seem to define "first" as the lowest possible row index with column index being second priority. Are you aware that scanning for this will result in sub-optimal iteration order for a column-major matrix? Are you able to transpose the input data and/or change the matrix to row-major? 2. How much do you prioritize an elegant solution over a fast one? 3. What matrix sizes and percentages of 0s do you expect?

Comment: This will apply to a video streaming process, matrix size N is about 20 but it will run lots of times per frame. Percentages of 0s is about 1/N(probably a few 0s per row) .

Answer (score 1):

As @chtz already suggested in comments, Eigen will not really help you here. We can still try to find a faster version.

Here is what I came up with:

First I expand / fix your code to have a working reference implementation.

```cpp
/**
 * Reference implementation
 * 
 * Finds lowest row and column (prioritizes low row number)
 * where cost_matrix is zero and both row_cover and col_cover are zero
 * 
 * Returns {-1, -1} if no result is found.
 * The input arrays can be overwritten by the implementation as desired
 */
std::pair<int, int> reference(
      Eigen::MatrixXi& cost_matrix,
      Eigen::VectorXi& row_cover,
      Eigen::VectorXi& col_cover) noexcept
{
    int i, j;
    cost_matrix.colwise() += row_cover;
    cost_matrix.rowwise() += col_cover.transpose();
    Eigen::Index zeroRow, zeroCol;
    int min = cost_matrix.transpose().minCoeff(&zeroCol, &zeroRow);
    i = zeroRow;
    j = zeroCol;
    if(min) // no result found
        return {-1, -1};
    return {i, j};
}
```

Going through the entire input matrix seems very wasteful unless the cover vectors are usually zero and the input matrix is not. If the cover contains many nonzero entries, it is better to convert them into vectors of zero indices.

```cpp
/**
 * Overwrite the front of cover with indices where it was zero
 * 
 * The return value gives the total number of zeros found.
 * The values behind that are left in undefined state
 */
static Eigen::Index to_zero_indices(Eigen::VectorXi& cover) noexcept
{
    Eigen::Index outpos = 0;
    for(Eigen::Index i = 0, n = cover.size(); i < n; ++i) {
        /* Loop body is written to be branchless */
        int value = cover[i];
        cover[outpos] = static_cast<int>(i);
        outpos += ! value;
    }
    return outpos;
}
```

Now we only need to check the entries in the matrix that zero in both covers.

```cpp
/**
 * Alternative implementation based on sparse probing of the cost matrix
 * 
 * API-compatible to reference but in practice changes the cover vectors,
 * not the cost matrix
 */
std::pair<int, int> probe_indices(
      Eigen::MatrixXi& cost_matrix,
      Eigen::VectorXi& row_cover,
      Eigen::VectorXi& col_cover) noexcept
{
    const Eigen::Index rows_n = to_zero_indices(row_cover);
    const Eigen::Index cols_n = to_zero_indices(col_cover);
    for(int i: row_cover.head(rows_n))
        for(int j: col_cover.head(cols_n))
            if(! cost_matrix(i, j))
                return {i, j};
    return {-1, -1};
}
```

For best results, compile with `-DNDEBUG` to avoid range checks in the various index operations.

### Testing

> matrix size N is about 20 but it will run lots of times per frame. Percentages of 0s is about 1/N(probably a few 0s per row)

I assume this 1/N does not apply to the cover vectors. Otherwise you have a very low chance of finding even one entry. I've arbitrarily decided to test with 4/N for the cover and 1/N for the cost matrix.

The full testing and benchmark result is below. On my system my version is about 10 times faster with the chosen parameter set and even if I change the cover to all zeros, it is 7.5 times faster. Even in the absolute worst case -- cover being all zero, matrix being all ones -- it's still twice as fast.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
// using std::default_random_engine, std::bernoulli_distribution
#include <utility>
// using std::pair


/**
 * Fill the output with zeros and ones depending on the percentage
 *
 * Results are random but reproducible across process executions.
 * Input percentage is expected to be between 0 and 1
 */
void fill_pct(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXi> out, double pct_ones)
{
    static std::default_random_engine::result_type seed = 0xdeadbeef;
    std::default_random_engine rng {seed++};
    std::bernoulli_distribution distr {pct_ones};
    out = Eigen::MatrixXi::NullaryExpr(
          out.rows(), out.cols(),
          [&]() -> int { return distr(rng); });
}
int main()
{
    using clock_t = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    const int size = 20;
    const double pct_zero = 1. / size;
    const double pct_zero_cover = 4. / size;
    const int repetitions = 1000000;
    Eigen::MatrixXi cost_matrix, matrix_copy;
    Eigen::VectorXi row_cover, col_cover, row_copy, col_copy;
    clock_t::duration reference_time {}, bench_time {};
    for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
        cost_matrix.resize(size, size);
        fill_pct(cost_matrix, 1. - pct_zero);
        matrix_copy = cost_matrix;
        for(Eigen::VectorXi* cover: {&row_cover, &col_cover}) {
            cover->resize(size);
            fill_pct(*cover, 1. - pct_zero_cover);
        }
        row_copy = row_cover;
        col_copy = col_cover;
        clock_t::time_point t1 = clock_t::now();
        std::pair<int, int> bench_result = probe_indices(
              cost_matrix, row_cover, col_cover);
        clock_t::time_point t2 = clock_t::now();
        std::pair<int, int> ref_result = reference(
              matrix_copy, row_copy, col_copy);
        clock_t::time_point t3 = clock_t::now();
        bench_time += t2 - t1;
        reference_time += t3 - t2;
        if(bench_result != ref_result)
            std::cout << bench_result.first << " != " << ref_result.first
                      << ' ' << bench_result.second << " != " << ref_result.second
                      << '\n';
    }
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;
    std::cout << "Reference " << std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                    reference_time).count() * 1e-3
              << "\nBench " << std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(
                    bench_time).count() * 1e-3
              << '\n';
}
```

### Further points

- As discussed in comments, it would be better to transpose the input and look for the first entry with priority on the first column. However, this only really becomes a big issue once the matrix is large enough that locality of data becomes a bigger concern
- I don't think explicit vectorization makes much sense. I feel like it could be done with gather instructions but that would only really work if the matrix is usually nonzero where the cover is zero
- In the case where row and column cover are mostly zero, we could invert the logic and scan the matrix first. This would also benefit from explicit vectorization

Addendum:
I did some tests with explicit AVX512 vectorization. First by making `to_zero_indices` use `vpcompressd`. This is slightly faster but not really worth it. Second I optimized the worst case above with some vectorized scans. It doubles performance in that particular case but supporting both patterns and deciding whether to use the scan or the regular operation has enough overhead to make the regular case half the speed. So not really useful.